# How I can output a smarty on foreach stdClass Object

Tags: arrays, foreach, smarty

I have a question:
I create a PHP File for array and a tpl for output my smarty.

PHP File

```
global $smarty;
$klar = $GLOBALS['DB']->executeQuery("SELECT * FROM my_table", 2);
```

That output looks like:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 220 [kAboID] => 1711000138 [kCustomerID] => 2 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 221 [kAboID] => 1711000145 [kCustomerID] => 2) )
```

If I only want Output kAboID from [0] I can use:

```
$oArray=$klar[0]->kAboID;
$smarty->assign("oArray",$oArray);
```

And use in TPL file

```
{$oArray}
```

And it will display like

> 1711000138

But how I need create that foreach that it will display like

> Nr: 1711000138
>
> Nr: 1711000145

Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new array in your PHP and assign whole array into tpl.

```
$oArray = array();
foreach ($klar as $row) {
    $oArray[] = $row->kAboID;
}
$smarty->assign("oArray", $oArray);
```

In tpl.

```
{foreach $oArray as $row}
    Nr. {$row}<br>
{/foreach}
```